# .NET x32 targeted app running as x64 on Ubuntu

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono, libgcc

So I'm trying to debug an issue my user is having with a piece of software on Ubuntu.

I have compiled a C# app targeted towards the the x86 platform, when running it on my x64 windows image the app operates as a x32 application.

[image]

However when running the same app though mono on Ubuntu it displays that it is x64

[image]

Which then causes the very nasty error of

> libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work

Comment: You have a 64bit version of Mono installed on your system which can only call into 64bit native libraries, it cannot use 32bit native libraries.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mono interop: Loading 32bit shared library does not work on my 64bit system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913946/mono-interop-loading-32bit-shared-library-does-not-work-on-my-64bit-system)

Comment: Without seeing your code and configuration, I don't see anything wrong yet.

Answer (score 0):

Mono that is compiled for 64-bit can only run apps in 64-bit mode. Similarly, Mono compiled for 32-bit can only run apps in 32-bit mode.

If you want to be able to run in either mode, then you need 2 versions of Mono - one compiled for 32-bit and one compiled for 64-bit.